# Is it possible to rewrite drivers for GPU not by manufacturer

Tags: driver, gpu

My GPU received new drivers from Windows Update. However last version of driver provided by Ati/AMD (not sure) available from the site is more than a year old. I do not know what happened. Microsoft wrote new drivers on his own? Microsoft forced AMD to that?

The questions are: Is it possible that someone has written his own GPU drivers which works on specific OS far better than drivers provided by the manufacturer? Would not it require technical documentation of the GPU (which probably is kept safe by the manufacturer)?

Comment: Sure,write your own drivers. People have done it before: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Drivers

Comment: @downrep_nation Maybe what you say is true, but the example is invalid. Quote from the wiki: 'They are not custom drivers compiled from source code.'

Comment: Well,nonetheless it's possible and the benefits are minimal because the manufacturers do the maximal effort to have the best performance possible to beat their competitors.